# overwrite write for once odoo version 10 python

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

method I  want to skip

```
@api.multi
def write(self, vals):
    if 'uom_id' in vals:
        new_uom = self.env['product.uom'].browse(vals['uom_id'])
        updated = self.filtered(lambda template: template.uom_id != new_uom)
        done_moves = self.env['stock.move'].search([('product_id', 'in', updated.mapped('product_variant_ids').ids)], limit=1)
        if done_moves:
            raise UserError(_("You can not change the unit of measure of a product that has already been used in a done stock move. If you need to change the unit of measure, you may deactivate this product."))
    return super(ProductTemplate, self).write(vals)
```

method I want to execute:

```
@api.multi
def write(self, vals):
    if 'uom_id' in vals:
        new_uom = self.env['product.uom'].browse(vals['uom_id'])
        updated = self.filtered(lambda template: template.uom_id != new_uom)
        done_moves = self.env['stock.move'].search([('product_id', 'in', updated.mapped('product_variant_ids').ids)], limit=1)
    print("@")   
    return super(my_product_class, self).write(vals)\
```

First write method is in the product.py that is a base class so I cannot change that so I want to execute my right method. How to do this?

Comment: You can try with a try except statement and catch that usererror and pass

Comment: Hey, can you please elaborate how to make it. Can you give me  a small example @dccdany

Answer (score 0):

class **my_product_class**(models.Model):

```
_inherit="product.template"


@api.multi
def write(self, vals):
    print(" ")
    return super(**ProductTemplate**, self).write(vals)
```

## here I have inherited the class In return method the name of the class that is suppose to be overwrite